# Duplicated users in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've set up Azure AD Connect on my server and synced users to Azure AD.

Now I have several users which are duplicated - for example

```
Name: John Doe
User principal name: john.doe@company.com
Directory synced: No

Name: John Doe
User principal name: john.doe3317@company.onmicrosoft.com
Directory synced: Yes
```

It seams like the latter is synced but with wrong "user principal name".

Question 1:
Can I just delete both accounts and let it sync again?

Question 2:
If I delete a user in Azure AD, will it delete the user in Office 365 and all their mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit [How to: Fix OnMicrosoft E-mail Address for Azure AD Sync Connected Users in Office365](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/140654-fix-onmicrosoft-e-mail-address-for-azure-ad-sync-connected-users-in-office365)

Here, the same issue is discussed. You might have to Manually force Azure AD Connect to run a full sync cycle. You can do this in two ways:

- Using PowerShell -
  https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/140656-manually-force-sync-azure-ad-connect-using-powershell
- GUI -
  https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/140653-force-manual-azure-ad-connect-sync

Comment: Thanks. Most users are synced fine with only the "mail" attribute .... should both "mail" and "targetAddress" be filled?

Comment: It's better to fill all details. But, if it works for you, you can skip it.

Comment: But the "targetAddress" can only be filled from within the "Attributes tab" right?

Answer (score 0):

When UserPrincipalName (UPN)/Alternate Login ID suffix is not verified with the Azure AD Tenant, then Azure Active Directory replaces the UPN suffixes with the default domain name "onmicrosoft.com".

When you create a user John.doe@company.com it will only have same UPN if the domain is verified in Azure AD which can be done by following.
Login to Azure > Azure AD > Customer domain name > add custom domain and make it primary.
The custom domain MX record needs to be verified.